# Customizing Author name/look of app.manifest for UAC Prompt

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, uac

As of now my UAC prompt comes up but it does not have my author name in it and it is yellow. How do I change that?

Thanks
Trevor Heins

Comment: This should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxw5c2s8.aspx

Comment: @NickS. that link is dead

Comment: @MattWilko I would only assume it to be dead since it is about 1 and a half years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have digitally sign your executable. That's the only way to have your name displayed as publisher and change the color of UAC to blue.

See [Digital Code Signing Step-by-Step Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140234%28v=office.10%29.aspx). The article talks about Office and Smart Tags, yet it can be used a guide to digitally sign other files.

The certificate you use for signing must be *trusted*, i.e. you have to buy it from a trusted Certificate Authority. If you sign your executable with self-signed certificate as shown in the article, it won't be trusted and nothing will change in the UAC prompt.